# Returning num_rows from php to javascript

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm working with some third party software and want to add the following functionality:

In a form, employees are able to capture contact data. This form is being checked by JavaScript before being passed to php for database writing.
Javascript does some basic checks, e.g. 'Firstname not empty'.
I want to add a check to see if a person already exists in the database WITHOUT setting the respective fields to unique in mySQL.

This is the syntax for other checks:

```
if (!RequiredField(frm.add_fd15.value)) {
nIndex++;
szAlert += "- " +"'Email Address' cannot be blank\n";
}
```

Now I want a call from javascript to a PHP segment that basically checks from the database query

```
SELECT count(*) FROM contacts WHERE firstname='$firstname' and lastname='$lastname'
```

The return value of this query then needs to be passed back to JavaScript.

How would I achieve this?

Comment: You should clarify here that you don't need to use AJAX because you are OK with refreshing the page as long as the form data is not lost.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php $num_rows = $result->num_rows; ?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var num_rows = <?php echo (is_int($num_rows)) ? $num_rows : 0; ?>; 
</script>
```

Comment: this looks simple and quick, I'll try and let you know :)

Comment: This answer makes sense although more is needed to explain how the form is to be refreshed without losing the form's data. (Simple, but should still be part of the answer.)

Answer (score 1):

look on this article

http://web.enavu.com/tutorials/checking-username-availability-with-ajax-using-jquery/

in this article we will make an ajax username availability checker powered with jQuery.

loop on the php after the query run , send ajax response 0 or 1

```
# //if number of rows fields is bigger them 0 that means it's NOT available '  
# if(mysql_num_rows($result)>0){  
#     //and we send 0 to the ajax request  
#     echo 0;  
# }else{  
#     //else if it's not bigger then 0, then it's available '  
#     //and we send 1 to the ajax request  
#     echo 1;  
# }
```

Comment: The asker didn't say he needs to avoid a page refresh when checking the form data before writing the form data to a database. Really, submitting the form without writing the data to the database is the simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

You'd need to make an AJAX request to your server, wait for the server reply, and then either allow further validation or inform the user that the row already exists. Thus, you'd need to stop the form from submitting until you've gotten a response from the server, and submit the form via JavaScript if the validation succeeds.

You can decide on the format of the server response yourself, just use something that you are able to parse as a JavaScript value/object, whether it is text, JSON or XML is really up to you.

Comment: Well, thats true if he is not OK with refreshing the page. Really he just said that the form data should not be written to the database, not that he can't submit the form without a database write. He didn't mention AJAX so I'm guessing that the asker is better off using the simpler page refresh solution.

Comment: True. But since he uses JavaScript validation I assumed that he didn't want a page refresh.